# Django save method and image proccesing

Tags: python, django

I have problem with saving the image with proper format when overriding save method in Model.

My code:

```
class Whatever(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="whatever")

    def save(self, *args, *kwargs):
        # Here I save file to the disk
        super(Whatever, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # Then i get this file
        filename = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + self.image.name
        # And do something with it
        img = cut_circle(filename, (42, 42), 42)
        # Now save it
        img.save(filename+)
```

And here is the problem, i need transparency in result image, but user can upload to server bad formats, jpeg for example.

So, how i can change file format in base? I tried self.image.save, but this way is complicated, i think.

Comment: I believe in your overloaded save function it should be `**kwargs` instead of `*kwargs`.

Comment: Oh, just a misprint, but thanks. Also, `filename` instead of `filename+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what library you are using to `cut_circle`, but if it is `PIL`, it can save the images in PNG by passing that as a format keyword argument; so you could do:

```
img.save(filename,format='png')
```

This seems fine for JPG; But if you want to retain the transparency of the formats like gif, you will need to take care of that one explicitly [as covered by Nadia](http://nadiana.com/pil-tips-converting-png-gif).